# Migrating a React class component's state to a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with Algolia in React, referencing this example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/algolia/doc-code-samples/tree/master/React%20InstantSearch/routing-basic?file=/src/App.js

For my project though I am using functional components. I am trying to figure out how to use the App component as a functional component, but am having some trouble figuring out this section of the code:

```
  state = {
    searchState: urlToSearchState(this.props.location),
    lastLocation: this.props.location,
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.location !== state.lastLocation) {
      return {
        searchState: urlToSearchState(props.location),
        lastLocation: props.location,
      };
    }

    return null;
  }

  onSearchStateChange = searchState => {
    clearTimeout(this.debouncedSetState);

    this.debouncedSetState = setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.history.push(
        searchStateToUrl(this.props, searchState),
        searchState
      );
    }, DEBOUNCE_TIME);

    this.setState({ searchState });
  };
```

I've handled state before in a functional component, but this looks a little confusing to me. Is there a way for this to be written as a functional component, specifically the state in the code above?

Answer (score 2):

I am going to break your code into 3 pieces and try to show how each can be turned into functional code .

#1 first part is setting your initial state

```
  state = {
    searchState: urlToSearchState(this.props.location),
    lastLocation: this.props.location,
  };
```

would be

```
  const [state , setState] = useState({
    searchState: urlToSearchState(props.location),
    lastLocation: props.location,
  })
```

#2  secondly reacting to the change of props.location value

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.location !== state.lastLocation) {
      return {
        searchState: urlToSearchState(props.location),
        lastLocation: props.location,
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
```

would be

```
  useEffect( () => {
     setState({
        searchState: urlToSearchState(props.location),
        lastLocation: props.location,
      })
  } , [ props.location ])
```

#3 thirdly reacting to the change of searchState value

```
  onSearchStateChange = searchState => {
    clearTimeout(this.debouncedSetState);

    this.debouncedSetState = setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.history.push(
        searchStateToUrl(this.props, searchState),
        searchState
      );
    }, DEBOUNCE_TIME);
    this.setState({ searchState });
  };
```

would be

```
  useEffect ( () => {
    clearTimeout(this.debouncedSetState);
    //handle debounce state at your own
    props.history.push(
        searchStateToUrl(props, searchState),
        searchState
    );
    setState({ ...state , searchState })
  } ,[])
```

Comment: Nice answer. You might want to mention that the input array for `useEffect` is mandatory (even if it is an empty array `[ ]`), and that the `useEffect()` will be re-run any time any of these input variables changes. Very well explained, though - *please answer more questions!*.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your answer. Would you mind taking a look at this error: https://codesandbox.io/s/late-http-q9nel?file=/src/App.js - im not sure why I'm getting "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'undefined.state')"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 const DEBOUNCE_TIME = 1000; // test, not in question's context
 const searchStateToUrl = (props, search) => console.log(search); // test, not in question's context
 const urlToSearchState = (loc) => console.log(loc); // test, not in question's context

 export default function AnsweredQuestion(props) {
   const { history, location } = props;

   const getSearchState = urlToSearchState(location);
   const [search, setSearch] = useState(getSearchState());
   const [lastLocation, setLastLocation] = useState(location);
   const [timerId, setTimerId] = useState(null);

   useEffect(() => {
     setSearch(getSearchState());
     setLastLocation(location);
   }, [location]); 

   const handleSearchStateChange = (updatedSearch) => {
     if (timerId) clearTimeout(timerId);

     const debounce = setTimeout(() => {
       history.push(searhStateToUrl(props, updatedSearch));
     }, DEBOUNCE_TIME);

     setTimerId(debounce);
     setSearch(updatedSearch);
   };
};
```

In my opinion, I like separating the state into separate variables. If I have more state to manage, I may use `useReducer` instead. The biggest thing here is that the `timerId` is stored in state, because we want to clear the timer if the search state changes. Also, `getDerviedStateFromProps` is synonymous with `useEffect`.